# Simple stack overflow exploit on linux x86_64

Tags: linux, memory-management, assembly, overflow, x86-64

I am following this tutorial (
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xonDJe3YxI ) with the server (which I compiled using the -m32 flag) running on a arch linux x86_64 machine.

Everything's fine but when I open the core dumps file with `gdb` it shows up that the `esp` address changes each time I run the application...

Why does the `esp` address change?
How can I handle this to keep following the tutorial?

Comment: Might it have something to do with the multithreading aspect of it?

Comment: Also, are you sure you have stack/address randomization disabled?

Comment: I am sure, it is enabled. Mostly this is a sign for it.

Comment: Yes! ASLR was the problem, thank you :)
So in a real world environment, where memory is randomized, what am I supposed to do for the "shellcode" section (from 32:15 to 40:37) of the video?

Comment: Did it occur to you that ASR was invented to *stop* people like you from injecting shell code from youtube videos?

Comment: I guess you were born with all the knowledge of the world in your brain so you have never needed to learn anything ;) - that's not the case for me anyway

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing something like this for the purposes of research/experimentation/education

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is quite possible there won't be such a thing as a simple exploit on x64. Amongst other issues you've already encountered e.g. ASLR, you also have to content with the fact the NX-bit is a feature of all x64-capable processors.

To find out if your CPU supports NX: `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "nx"`. If you see `nx` highlighted in the flags, you have the NX bit and the kernel is probably using it.

The NX-bit is a hardware-supported method (well, technically, the kernel indicates which pages should not be executed) to say "this area of memory here, don't execute it ever". This is commonly applied to the stack, as it neatly defeats any kind of injected shell code. Your stack based exploit likely overwrites jump to wherever you want - i.e. the buffer you just inserted with your nullfree code. Except that now the processor raises a fault instead of moving eip/rip there.

You can turn this off, but you need to do it on a per-process basis as the flags for this are part of the ELF. To do this, use the `execstack` utility, which can also query the status of the executable stack.

You can also do this post build with `gcc -z execstack`.

As you have no doubt realised, this is not a common real world scenario. There are binaries on Linux running with execstack (Nvidia graphics components are I believe one) but they're rare.

As I understand it, you've managed ASLR, but for others that might read this you can turn it off with:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

as root.

The way around non-executable stacks (which can be hindered by ASLR) is to use return-orientated programming. A very, very simple overview: since you get to overwrite the stack, you can write a stack that looks like a stack frame (or a series of stack frames) for known functions, like the C standard library. These let you run libc functions, which are quite powerful in what they can achieve. You're not limited to libc, though.

A windows focused tutorial for this is [available here](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2010/06/16/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-10-chaining-dep-with-rop-the-rubikstm-cube/).

Comment: Dang, how could I forget about the NX bit :P